# Quasar: How to get a value from an array object?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework

I would like to get the first `value` which has the `key`:`name` from an array object. The code `quasar` provides give me all the `vlaue` and `keys` when it's selected.

So from the data above, I wish to get only selected `value`.

Like this:
[image]

I tried `Object.value()`, `JSON.stringify()`, and `localStorage.setItem()`, but did not see what I want.

Here is the basic sample from `Quasar`

template:

```js
<template>
  <div class="q-pa-md">
    <q-table
      title="Treats"
      :data="data"
      :columns="columns"
      row-key="name"
      :selected-rows-label="getSelectedString"
      selection="multiple"
      :selected.sync="selected"
    />

    <div class="q-mt-md">
      Selected: {{ JSON.stringify(selected) }} 
      
      <!-- Original Result : 
      Selected: [{"name":"Ice cream sandwich", "calories":237, 
      "fat":9, "carbs":37, "protein":4.3, "sodium":129,
      "calcium":"8%", 
      -->
      
      <!--  Desired Result :
      Selected: *Value I Selected without [{}]*  
    -->
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

script:

```js
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      selected: [],
      columns: [
        {
          name: 'desc',
          required: true,
          label: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'left',
          field: row => row.name,
          format: val => `${val}`,
          sortable: true
        },
        { name: 'calories', align: 'center', label: 'Calories', field: 'calories', sortable: true },
      ],
      data: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          sodium: 87,
          calcium: '14%',
          iron: '1%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          sodium: 129,
          calcium: '8%',
          iron: '1%'
        },
      
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getSelectedString () {
      // I also thought I may need to use this function,
      // but have no idea how to approach..
      return this.selected.length === 0 ? '' : `${this.selected.length} record${this.selected.length > 1 ? 's' : ''} selected of ${this.data.length}`
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

It feels like this is such a minor thing, but sadly I have spent few hours on this.. It would be so grateful if you let me know how to solve this!

Comment: So do you want to get the output `['Frozen Yogurt', 'Ice Creame Sandwich']` from your data array, or you want to filter out all array items to get only `Icecream sandwich`? Am I getting it right?

Comment: @SnazzyMohit I want only one value, `Icecream sandwich` so that I can add additional sentence behind such as `Icecream sandwich` has been selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the map method

```js
data.map(dessert => dessert.name)[0]
```

**Explanation**: `data.map()` returns a list with the return value of its callback, of which the first parameter is the iterated value in the source (`data` here)

Then we could select the first value of the iterated list (that is `ice creame sandwich`)

**Edit**: I saw the comment and accordingly edited the question. All you need to do is to get the object from the array by selecting the first index like `array[0]`, then select the name like `array[0].name`

**This is what you exactly need:**

```js
Selected: {{ selected[0].name }}
```

PS: I hope you're a beginner. I would suggest you to take at least a JavaScript course on w3schools, and learn more about arrays and objects (I think you already know HTML and CSS). For future reference, you could have searched

> how to get javascript array nested object value

Would have saved you a question...

Comment: Let me know if this needs any improvement, or if the question was misunderstood.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my question. It is not only for the 'Ice Sandwich', but anything I selected. Now, what I see is all the values in the object. Would you kindly re-check my question?

Comment: @Uheny I've edited the question accordingly. Hope it helps, and don't forget to mark check-mark and upvote the answer (if you haven't already) if you find it helpful so that others could find it easily. Thanks...

Comment: Thank you, Snazzy. It might sound like an excuse, but I indeed tried `selected[0].name`, but did not show me the desired result (but now it works.. idk why), and like you said, `selected.map(item => item.name)[0]` also works! 

I know I really need to learn more about the fundamental knowledge on javascript. Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

do you want to map?

```js
var data = [ {name: "AA"}, {name: "BB"}]:
var result =  data.map( (ob) => { return ob.name; });
// result contains ["AA", "BB"]
var result2 =  result.join(", ")
// result2 contains "AA, BB"

data[0].name // returns AA
```

Comment: Ah.. This is not what I have answered, but many thanks. I wish to get only 'one word', which is 'Ice sandwich', and there is only one `object` in the `array`

Comment: i mean just one of an array? i added this as well... question is a bit unclear in this case

Comment: @bkr ikr, it was edited but still a bit unclear imo

Comment: @bkr Yes, I realised my question was blur, so I have edited it, so where in my `template` could I use your code?

Comment: @SnazzyMohit I have added an image to clarify better.